# HTML modal popup, display results by calling php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hopefully a simple question regarding dynamically populating results to a popup model rather than opening a new page.

I have a html table of results based on a php query, when I highlight a row and click the edit button a new window opens and displays more details about the selected item. This is working fine but now I would like to have to contents display in a model instead of opening a new page.

Below is the JavaScript for the **edit** button that does work.

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnEdit').click(function(e) {
        var value = $("#tblTickets tr.selected td:eq(4)").html();
        window.open("helpdesk_ticket_details.php?ID="+value);       
    });
});
```

Now if I modify the code slightly like below the model box displays but I'm not sure how to dynamically fill it based on my table selection.

```
$(function() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    $('#btnEdit').click(function(e) {
        var value = $("#tblTickets tr.selected td:eq(4)");
        modal.style.display = 'block';
    });
});
```

Any help on this is appreciated. If you need anymore information please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you feel adding model code as well as HTML table structure would make more sense ?

Comment: Sure, but I'm not sure where to start. Would pasting more of my code help?

Comment: Adding relevant code would help! Nobody likes to read and understand lengthy code..

Comment: I'm not sure what would be helpful. I'm pretty happy with how it works now. The model is more a cosmetic thing. If it's going to mean changing a lot of code to get the result I'm after, I'll just leave it opening in another window. I just thought changing some of the JavaScript code would be enough (plus modifying my css files). I've tried modal.modal-body = <?php include("helpdesk_ticket_details.php");?>; to call the php file but it didn't work.

Comment: Yes..it is going to be few lines of code...not a _lot_ ;)

Comment: Alright, so where do we start? What piece of code would be useful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104951/discussion-between-user2168287-and-rayon-dabre).

Comment: Have you thought about doing this in Ajax an just populating an empty div/span with html?